# Is Gitlab the only vendor support subgroups level git repos?

Tags: git, gitlab, github, bitbucket

Try to evaluate a few SaaS Git providers (e.g., Github, Bitbucket) other than Gitlab, but I don't think any of them support a subgroup level repo

```
mycompany/backend/core.git
mycompany/devtools.git
mycompany/security/scanner.git
mycompany/mobile/ios/consumer.git
mycompany/mobile/ios/enterprise.git
```

I don't want to sign-up for Github/Bitbucket in order to test this out, does anyone knows the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket and Github don't have subgroups.
They have a more flexible approach, where you can create teams or user-groups which have access to project groups.

You can get the same functionality - with some operational overhead to set it up.

However, since this is not server-related, this question might better be asked on a more dev-oriented platform.

Comment: Thanks, I actually do not know which StackExchange to post this question, but thanks for pointing out.